# prolog program for sum of all even fibonacci numbers below 4000000

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

I need a solution in prolog. I am trying but did not get the correct answer.
Kindly solve my problem by providing correct code.

```
A(1).
B(1).
Value(0).
fib(N, Value) :-
  A is N <= 4000000, fib(A, A1),
  B is N % 2 == 0, fib(B, B1):-
 
  Value is +=A &&
  A,B = B, A1+B1.
  print Value.
```

Comment: First start by writing simple Prolog programs. Not even the syntax is ok.

Comment: its my assignment i need a solve that

Comment: Like you said yourself, **you** need to solve that.

Comment: @JamesZ I solved this problem in python but having a difficulty with Prolog.

Comment: But its your assignment how will you solve it?

Comment: Now I see you just wrote some combination of Prolog and Python in your question. Good work you should get half points for this assignment. How much to pass?

Comment: I solved my problem thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

```
test2:-
    writeln("problem2(4000000,2,4613732) should be true."),
    time(problem2(4000000,2,4613732)).

problem2(B,M,S5):-
    [B,M] ins 1..sup,
    genfib(0,1,B,LF),
    include({M}/[X2]>> #=(mod(X2,M),0),LF,LN),
    sum_list(LN,S5).

genfib(N1,N2,B,[N|LF]):-
   N #= N1+N2,
  `N #=< B,`
    genfib(N2,N,B,LF),
    !.
genfib(_,_,_,[]).
```